# Update pandas DataFrame Multilevel Index with a Series?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a `DataFrame` with a multi-level index (in this example 'userId' & 'date' are part of the index):

```
                 clicks
userId   date
x        1/1     1
         1/2     2
y        1/1     3
         1/3     4
z        1/1     4
```

And given a `Series` that has values from the first level of the DataFrame's multi-index as its own index:

```
x    Alice
z    Charlie
y    Bob
```

**How can the first level of the DataFrame index be updated to be the values from a Series?**  The resulting DataFrame would look like

```
Alice    1/1     1
         1/2     2
Bob      1/1     3
         1/3     4
Charlie  1/1     4
```

Note: I cannot rely on the ordering of the Series being the same ordering as the first level of the multi-index (e.g. the Series index is ['x', 'z', 'y'] while the DataFrame first-level is ['x', 'y', 'z'])

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the level using the Series, then assign the index back.

```
import pandas as pd

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
            [df.index.get_level_values('userId').map(s),  # s is your Series
             df.index.get_level_values('date')])
```

---

```
             clicks
userId  date        
Alice   1/1        1
        1/2        2
Bob     1/1        3
        1/3        4
Charlie 1/1        4
```

Comment: Does the `.map` assume that the Series index and the `userId` index are the same ordering?

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil No, it's a mapping of values based on the Index of the Series. So it translates 'x' - > 'Alice', as if it were using the dictionary `{'x': 'Alice', 'y': 'Bob', 'z': 'Charlie'}`